# Prove that the product of two Lipschitz functions is locally Lipschitz.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space and $f_{i}\colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Lipschitz functions. Set $f=f_{1}f_{2}$.

How to prove that $f$ is locally Lipschitz?

Comment: derivative of a product of two functions will give you a hint.

Comment: But I don't know if I can differentiate the product? What about $f_{i}(x)=|x|$?

Comment: I said, a hint. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
   |f(x)-f(y)|
{}={}&
   |f_1(x){}\cdot{}f_2(x)-f_1(y){}\cdot{}f_2(y)| 
\\
{}={}& 
   |(f_1(x)-f_1(y))f_2(x)+f_1(y)(f_2(x)-f_2(y))|
\\
{}\leq{}& 
   |f_1(x)-f_1(y)|{}\cdot{}|f_2(x)|+|f_1(y)|{}\cdot{}|f_2(x)-f_2(y)|.\end{align}

Now, by Lip of $f_i$ we have a bound of $Ld(x,y)$ on differences. It suffices to prove local boundedness of $f_i$.

Comment: So convexity has nothing to do with the proof.